# PHP best way to return custom message with header status code

Tags: php, jquery, http-headers

Where is the best place to put a custom response message. I will need to access the response message with jquery and alert it to the user

```
function return_status($code, $message) {



    //This way
    header("HTTP/1.1 $code $message");
    die();

   //OR This way
   header('Content-Type: application/json');
   header("HTTP/1.1 $code");
   die(json_encode(['code' => $code, 'message' => $message]));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While headers are easy to access, it's not a good idea to change the text associated to a status code.  Your second method would be best.

Using your second method,let's say you'd done $.getJSON.

```
return $.getJSON('my-php-script.php')
    .then(
       function (data) { /* do something with data */},
       function (error) { /* do something with error */}
    )
```